# Show the next 5 products from a products collection

Tags: shopify

Instead of doing "You may like" I'm trying to cheat a little and display the next 5 products within the current products collection at the bottom of the product page.

Is this possible with Shopify?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. If you have the collection in your URL or if you get the first collection that the product is present.

Comment: I reckon steal the code from the Product template, and as long as it detects the proper category you can use that for loop to show 5 products from that category.

Comment: But both of these don't show the next products? so it'd only be showing the first 5 of the collection every time?

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah, Shopify doesn't have that concept of "The next _n_" as something you can easily tap into.  If it has to be the 5 products after the current one, the only thing I know that you can do is to grab a list of products using javascript/AJAX, find the starting index based on your current product, then render the next _n_ from there (presumably looping around to the front if you reach the end)